# Can you make an equilateral triangle from 3identical trapezoids?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Is it possible to make an equilateral triangle from 3 **identical** trapezoids? If so, what angles would be needed in the trapezoids?

Answer (score 12):

[image]

These are all $60^\circ$ equilateral triangles, 3 to the trapezoid. So these are isosceles trapazoids having two $60^\circ$ angles and two $120^\circ$ angles.